# attempted relative import with no known parent package python

Tags: python, python-3.x

After saving my main.py file for FastAPI web server,  I have received this error:

```
    from . import models
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Inside main.py, I was trying to import models.py file to main.py. Both files are under same directory:

```
from . import models
```

[image]

Comment: models.py is not in the Parent directory, so you should use `import models`